# Time series with matrix

Tags: python, matrix, time, series

I have a mat extension data which I want to separate every seconds values. My matrix is `(7,5,2500)` time series 3 dimensional matrix which want to get the values of `(7,5,1) ...(7,5,2500)` separately and save it

for example

```
array([155,  33, 129,167,189,63,35
       161, 218,   6,58,36,25,3

       89,63,36,25,78,95,21
       78,52,36,56,25,15,68
       ]],

       [215, 142, 235,
        143, 249, 164],

       [221,  71, 229,
         56,  91, 120],

       [236,   4, 177,
        171, 105,  40])
```

for getting every part of this data for example this matrix

```
  [215, 142, 235,
  143, 249, 164]
```

what should I do?

Comment: `chain = list(itertools.chain(*a))` where `a` is multidimensional list.

Comment: I want to separate every second value and save it

Comment: do you mean `T[1]`? (assuming your array is named `T`)

Comment: Yes for example for first second  [155,  33, 129,
        161, 218,   6]] this value , for next second  [215, 142, 235,
        143, 249, 164] and for third second [236,   4, 177,
        171, 105,  40]  and son on .

Comment: I have (7,5,2500) matrix and i want to get value of (7,5,1) ,(7,5,2),(7,5,3)and ... son an

Comment: I'm sorry, could you please explain your question a bit better? It's really not clear...

Comment: yes I have a mat extension  data which i want to separate every seconds values  my matrix is (7,5,2500)  time series 3 dimensional matrix which want to get the values  of (7,5,1) ...(7,5,2500)  separately  and save it

Comment: But that does not match the data you've posted...

Comment: Yes you are right @toti08 but what is the solution you think just i put it as example i cant put whole 2500 value.

Comment: No, but at least the first elements should match your description....

Comment: Yes you are right @toti08  but do you have solution for it ?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is array slicing, I've posted an answer explaining it, but please edit your question and make it more clear, as it's really difficult to understand what you want...

Comment: Ok for sure if you think it iteration to iterate the value what should I do ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your question...

Comment: if i want to iterate it through the 2500 example and save it automatically what should i do ? I mean (7,5,1) (7,5,2)... @toti08

Comment: Save it where? In an array, a dictionary, ...? How are you going to use this data?

Comment: @toti08 save it as  a new matrix in directory  ı am going to turn in to image.

Comment: You can select the part of the matrix you need to create the image directly from your (7,5,2500) matrix using slicing, without the need to save it separately. I'll try to update my answer...

Comment: Yes if you can help me it will be great i am new in python. @toti08

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [[155,  33, 129, 161, 218,   6],
     [215, 142, 235, 143, 249, 164],
     [221,  71, 229,  56,  91, 120],
     [236,   4, 177, 171, 105,  40]]

print(a[1])
```

Comment: I have (7,5,2500) matrix and i want to get value of (7,5,1) ,(7,5,2),(7,5,3)and ... son an

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your data saved in a `numpy` array you could use [slicing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#arrays-indexing) to extract the sub-matrices you need. Here is an example with a `(3,5,3)` matrix (but the example could be applied to any dimension):

```
A = numpy.array([[[1,1,1],
                  [2,2,2],
                  [3,3,3],
                  [4,4,4],
                  [5,5,5]],

                  [[11,11,11],
                  [21,21,21],
                  [31,31,31],
                  [41,41,41],
                  [51,51,51]],

                  [[12,12,12],
                  [22,22,22],
                  [32,32,32],
                  [42,42,42],
                  [52,52,52]]]
sub_matrix_1 = A[:,:,0]
print (sub_matrix_1)
```

Will produce:

```
[[ 1  2  3  4  5]
 [11 21 31 41 51]
 [12 22 32 42 52]]
```

EDIT: it is also possible to iterate over the array to get the 3rd dimension array:

```
for i in range(A.shape[-1]):
    print (A[:,:,i])
    # Your submatrix is A[:,:,i], you can directly manipulate it
```

Comment: please let me know how to save this printed data ?

Comment: You could for example save it in a csv file, but that depends on what's your goal. I've put a print just as an example, but you can replace the print with any calculation.

Comment: My goal is turn sub_matrix in to grayscale images and concatenate all images @toti08

Comment: if you think this question is ok please upvote this question. Thanks